# Returning value from duplicate rows based on specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a specific requirement to return a particular value for the same ID. For eg, my table contains :

```
O345215  | MemberID1
O232321  | MemberID2
M434555  | MemberID2
O200022  | MemberID3
M997821  | MemberID4
O898989  | MemberID5
M454545  | MemberID5
```

I would like the result to be like this:

```
O345215  | MemberID1
M434555  | MemberID2
O200022  | MemberID3
M997821  | MemberID4
M454545  | MemberID5
```

If the `MemberID` contains rows with values starting with O and M, then return only the row/value that starts with "M", but if the ID contains only a single row (irrespective of if it starts with O or M), then simply return whatever is present.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If this is in your table and nothing else, a simple `SELECT MemberID, MIN(Value) GROUP BY MemberID` would do, since `M < O`. Of course there are scenarios where this approach can fail (multiple `M` records and you want a specific one, things before `M`).

Comment: Thankyou very much. This works for my purposes, even though as you mentioned, it may not be totally correct in other scenarios. But for this particular O/M which are business related, it does the trick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value like '[OM]%' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.memberid = t.memberid and t2.value like '[OM]%' 
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. So adjust accordingly, the `#test` table would be your table name.

```
create table #test (id varchar(20), member varchar(20))

insert into #test values
('O345215',   'MemberID1')
,('O232321' ,  'MemberID2')
,('M434555' ,  'MemberID2')
,('O200022' ,  'MemberID3')
,('M997821' ,  'MemberID4')
,('O898989' ,  'MemberID5')
,('M454545' ,  'MemberID5')



SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(member) > 1 THEN member
       END AS dup_member
INTO #dup
FROM #test
GROUP BY member

SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(member) = 1 THEN member
       END AS one_member
INTO #one
FROM #test
GROUP BY member
ORDER BY 1

SELECT t.*
FROM #test t
     LEFT JOIN #dup d ON t.member = d.dup_member
     LEFT JOIN #one o ON o.one_member = t.member
WHERE id LIKE CASE
                  WHEN dup_member IS NOT NULL THEN 'm%'
                  ELSE id
              END
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen Mostert mentioned, this would give you correct results in this particular instance because M < O
`SELECT MemberID, MIN(Value) GROUP BY MemberID`

In the general case, there is no need to scan the table twice. You can do this with row numbering and a single scan:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Value LIKE 'O%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM table t
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```